# How to import a text file from firebase into kotlin app?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to import a text from txt file uploaded on Firebase to my text-view of the Kotlin App.
Can anyone guide me through the steps?

Please mention the code for Kotlin as other articles on this topic are related to java files.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried already? Is the text stored in Firestore, Firebase Storage, or Realtime Database? Is it the binary of the file or is it the actual text from the file? What documentation have you used already?

Comment: It's a little too broad to reasonably answer, here on Stackoverflow. Have you tried something already?

Comment: Hi, The text file is saved inside Firebase Storage. I'm not able to find much resources on this. So I don't know how to start